# push array momentJS hours utc

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to format hours . l want to get every 6 hours as array .

expected outcome hours release

```
[6,12,24,36,48];
```

output which i have after run the code

```
    [6,12,6,12,6];
```

code :

```
    let date = moment();
    this.hours = []

        for (let i = 0 i <= 4; i++) {
           
            this.hours.push(date.add(6,"hour").format("h"))
        }
```

any solution please ?

Comment: 24 is not 6 hours after 12. 18 is 6 hours after 12. 18:00 is 6:00 pm, which is why you're getting 6 in the third place. If you want a running total, just push `6 * (i + 1)`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you for commented , can you give me full answer please ?

Comment: You should update your question with how your expected outcome relates to your desired pattern.

Comment: @HereticMonkey updated

Comment: @HereticMonkey expected outcome hours release

`[6,12,24,36,48]`;

Comment: You expected outcome is not every 6 hours, as I said in my first comment. Figure out what you actually want.

Comment: @HereticMonkey , okay how i can i get hours `[6,12,24,36,48]` from momentjs ? should i use add function ? like `moment().add(6,"hours)` ?

Comment: I don't know why you're hung up on using momentjs to create a list of 5 numbers.

Comment: @HereticMonkey check out this link please . http://bader.arabiaweather.com/#mode=forecast/provider=gem/region=levant/image=accumulated-precipitation/runTime=20200921T120000/time=6/timeEvery=6 . You will find numbers in toolbar bottom . divide every 6 hours

Comment: i want to get this hours https://i.ibb.co/1RhkjLt/Screen-Shot-2020-09-21-at-11-36-05-PM.png using moment js

Comment: That's not every 6 hours, that is quite different. If you click on 072, for instance, that number gets bigger, and the numbers around it get larger (font-size-wise) and less far apart the closer to the selected number: 000 012 024 036 048 060 066 *069*
**072** *075* 078 084 096 108 120 132 144 156 168 180 192 204 216 228 240

Comment: @HereticMonkey , So what is your suggestion ?

Comment: I can see that you don't want to do your own research on this, but that's what you need to do. You need to look at how those numbers differ from one another and figure out what an accurate algorithm to reproduce them is.

Comment: @HereticMonkey l am beginner . Thank you for your time .

Answer (score 0):

```
// let date = moment();
this.hours = []

    for (let i = 0 i <= 4; i++) {
       if(i === 0)this.hours.push(6);
       this.hours.push(12*i);
        //this.hours.push(date.add(6,"hour").format("h"))
    }
```

Comment: thank you for answering , l am not getting same result which i want !

Comment: Answers which are just code with no explanation are less useful than those which explain the code. Especially when the code is just a copy of someone else's comment ;)

Comment: @AgniswarMandal not that which i want bro . check out my update question